# view in a real-time database in the firebase console

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

[image: My data screen looks like this:]

I have an existing project in firebase and the data are displayed in the run of the site but I want to view in a real-time database in the firebase console do not see the data

Comment: First try refreshing the page.  If the Firebase console doesn't appear the way that you expect, please contact Firebase support directly to report a problem. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: you need a 'root', try to click at "+" button